# Como puedo seleccionar datos específicos de un texto con PHP?

Tags: php

Hola tengo un problema quiero hacer una lista de las link que terminan solo con .MP4 estoy usando esta funcion pero no me funciona como yo quiero si uso la funcion `foreach()` solo me da un link en esta caso que puedo hacer bueno espero que me ayuden y gracias

[image]

**Codígo EJ:**

```
                $count = preg_match_all('/(.+)([^&]+).(MP4|3gp)/',$content,$matches);
                if ($count > 0) {
                    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                        echo $matches[1][$i].'<br>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo('error');
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**1** Usando pathinfo y parseurl

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$urls = array(
  "https://www.example.com/back",
  "http://www.example.com/badge.htm",
  "https://www.example.com/acoustics/ants.mp4",
  "http://www.example.com/bat.html",
  "http://www.example.com/#acoustics",
  "http://www.example.com/",
  "https://example.com/boot/book",
  "https://example.com/?branch=bath",
  "http://example.com/",
  "https://www.example.com/babies",
  "http://www.example.com/filename.mp4?bone=agreement",
  "https://belief.example.com/arithmetic",
  "http://www.example.com/believe/badge#book",
  "https://www.example.com/basket/branch.mp4",
  "https://www.example.com/brake.html?advice=book&birthday=birds",
  "http://www.example.net/book.php",
);
$filtrados = array();

$buscar="mp4";

foreach ($urls as $url) :
  if ($buscar===pathinfo(parse_url($url)['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) :
    $filtrados[] = $url;
  endif;
endforeach;

print_r($filtrados);
```

Resultado

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.example.com/acoustics/ants.mp4
    [1] => http://www.example.com/filename.mp4?bone=agreement
    [2] => https://www.example.com/basket/branch.mp4
)
```

**2** O en un sentido mas general podes buscar la subcadena al final y compararla con la cadena a buscar (pero falla si hay parametros extra)

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$urls = array(
  "https://www.example.com/back",
  "http://www.example.com/badge.htm",
  "https://www.example.com/acoustics/ants.mp4",
  "http://www.example.com/bat.html",
  "https://example.com/?branch=bath",
  "http://example.com/",
  "https://www.example.com/babies",
  "http://www.example.com/filename.mp4?bone=agreement",
  "https://belief.example.com/arithmetic",
  "http://www.example.com/believe/badge#book",
  "https://www.example.com/basket/branch.mp4",
  "https://www.example.com/brake.html?advice=book&birthday=birds",
  "http://www.example.net/book.php",
);
$filtrados = array();

$buscar=".mp4";

foreach ($urls as $url) :
  if ($buscar===substr($url, -strlen($buscar))) :
    $filtrados[] = $url;
  endif;
endforeach;

print_r($filtrados);
```

Resultado: **No reconoció la que tiene un parámetro**

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.example.com/acoustics/ants.mp4
    [1] => https://www.example.com/basket/branch.mp4
)
```

si necesitas filtrar por varias extensiones lo pones todo en una funcion y la llamas en el if.